# One Time Pad proof for Perfect Secrecy

Tags: one-time-pad, perfect-secrecy

In the book "Introduction to Cryptography with Coding Theory" by Trappe, in the paragraph about the security of the One Time Pad, is it told that given the set of possible plaintexts $P$, the set of possible keys $K$ and the set of possible ciphertext $C$, then:

$H(P,K,C)=H(P,K)=H(P,C)$

However, he doesn't explain why. Can you show me ? If possible also formally

Comment: What does the function $H$ represent?